# Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException, Unable to obtain a new access

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud

I am working on **Spring Cloud** small POC and getting the below error. I was trying to access the resources using the token which I got using this method [o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint : Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Bad credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746353/o-s-s-o-provider-endpoint-tokenendpoint-handling-error-invalidgrantexception) . Could you please guide me what's wrong ?

> Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException, Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }   
}
```

**CustomUserInfoTokenServices**

```
public class CustomUserInfoTokenServices implements ResourceServerTokenServices {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private static final String[] PRINCIPAL_KEYS = new String[] { "user", "username",
            "userid", "user_id", "login", "id", "name" };

    private final String userInfoEndpointUrl;

    private final String clientId;

    private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    private String tokenType = DefaultOAuth2AccessToken.BEARER_TYPE;

    private AuthoritiesExtractor authoritiesExtractor = new FixedAuthoritiesExtractor();

    public CustomUserInfoTokenServices(String userInfoEndpointUrl, String clientId) {
        this.userInfoEndpointUrl = userInfoEndpointUrl;
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public void setRestTemplate(OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public void setAuthoritiesExtractor(AuthoritiesExtractor authoritiesExtractor) {
        this.authoritiesExtractor = authoritiesExtractor;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessToken)
            throws AuthenticationException, InvalidTokenException {
        Map<String, Object> map = getMap(this.userInfoEndpointUrl, accessToken);
        if (map.containsKey("error")) {
            this.logger.debug("userinfo returned error: " + map.get("error"));
            throw new InvalidTokenException(accessToken);
        }
        return extractAuthentication(map);
    }

    private OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Object principal = getPrincipal(map);
        OAuth2Request request = getRequest(map);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = this.authoritiesExtractor
                .extractAuthorities(map);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                principal, "N/A", authorities);
        token.setDetails(map);
        return new OAuth2Authentication(request, token);
    }

    private Object getPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {
        for (String key : PRINCIPAL_KEYS) {
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                return map.get(key);
            }
        }
        return "unknown";
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    private OAuth2Request getRequest(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Map<String, Object> request = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("oauth2Request");

        String clientId = (String) request.get("clientId");
        Set<String> scope = new LinkedHashSet<>(request.containsKey("scope") ?
                (Collection<String>) request.get("scope") : Collections.<String>emptySet());

        return new OAuth2Request(null, clientId, null, true, new HashSet<>(scope),
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken readAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported: read access token");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    private Map<String, Object> getMap(String path, String accessToken) {
        this.logger.info("Getting user info from: " + path);
        try {
            OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = this.restTemplate;
            if (restTemplate == null) {
                BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource = new BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails();
                resource.setClientId(this.clientId);
                restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource);
            }
            OAuth2AccessToken existingToken = restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext()
                    .getAccessToken();
            if (existingToken == null || !accessToken.equals(existingToken.getValue())) {
                DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(
                        accessToken);
                token.setTokenType(this.tokenType);
                restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(token);
            }
            return restTemplate.getForEntity(path, Map.class).getBody();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.logger.info("Could not fetch user details: " + ex.getClass() + ", "
                    + ex.getMessage());
            return Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("error",
                    "Could not fetch user details");
        }
    }
```

**PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecureserviceApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecureserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecureserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

    // added
    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerProperties sso;

    // added
    @Bean
    public ResourceServerTokenServices myUserInfoTokenServices() {
        return new CustomUserInfoTokenServices(sso.getUserInfoUri(), sso.getClientId());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/tolldata")
    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('toll_read') and hasAuthority('ROLE_OPERATOR')")
    public ArrayList<TollUsage> getTollData() {

        TollUsage instance1 = new TollUsage("200", "station150", "B65GT1W", "2016-09-30T06:31:22");
        TollUsage instance2 = new TollUsage("201", "station119", "AHY673B", "2016-09-30T06:32:50");
        TollUsage instance3 = new TollUsage("202", "station150", "ZN2GP0", "2016-09-30T06:37:01");

        ArrayList<TollUsage> tolls = new ArrayList<TollUsage>();
        tolls.add(instance1);
        tolls.add(instance2);
        tolls.add(instance3);

        return tolls;
    }

    public class TollUsage {

        public String Id;
        public String stationId;
        public String licensePlate;
        public String timestamp;

        public TollUsage() {
        }

        public TollUsage(String id, String stationid, String licenseplate, String timestamp) {
            this.Id = id;
            this.stationId = stationid;
            this.licensePlate = licenseplate;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]